# Can we isolate the iron ions in a solution?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrochemistry, ions

I was wondering if it was possible to isolate the iron ions in a soltion without adding anything (to precipitate for example).
Maybe using a magnetic field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A magnetic field won't do anything, but if you apply an electric field you can [electrolyse the iron salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis) and produce metallic iron.

There are some other more involved ways it could be done. For example zeolites will selectively absorb some metal ions. If you choose the correct zeolite you could remove all the iron. Though arguably this is just a form of precipitation. Actually if you wanted to go this route I imagine there must be [ion exchange resins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion-exchange_resin) that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If iron is dissolved in water (polar liquid), it will be in the form of ions. If we apply uniform magnetic field these ions will gyrate around this magnetic field and will do nothing but if we apply a non uniform magnetic field and the non uniformity is perpendicular to the direction of magnetic lines the ions will slowly drift from high field region to low field region (regardless of their charge). This phenomena is known as [grad B drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guiding_center).

Hence yes if you apply magnetic field the ions can be separated (and not only iron but all the ions).

However there are other factors, These precipitated ions can again get dissolved in water due to motion of water molecules hence in order to see the deposition you must have rate of precipitation > rate of dissolution. As the ions start to precipitate their concentration in the water decreases which decreases the rate of precipitation and increases rate of dissolution.

Hence in principle you can separate the ions from water by magnetic field but I dont know how practical this will be.

Hope this will help